# How to not display JQuery tabbed content when page loads

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

I would like to have the JQuery tabs act like a nav bar where no tabbed content displays until the user clicks a tab.

I have this code that hides the tabbed content but also breaks the tabs so they don't display content when clicked. I cannot figure out the syntax and would love some help. I'm only accessing static HTML content.

```
<pre><script>
$(function() {
    $( "div.panes" ).panes({ selected: -1 });
$("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
});
</script></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQueryUI tabs. That works better than reinventing the wheel.